# How to create local connection in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I only have SQL Developer installed. What other programs do I need to install to create a local database. Please provide links.

[image]

Comment: You'd need to download and install the Oracle database.  There are multiple versions and editions that you could download from the OTN site (the same place that you, presumably, downloaded SQL Developer from).  You could, for example, grab the express edition of 11.2.  Or the enterprise edition of 12.1.

Comment: I talk about this here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/

Comment: I have installed XE 11.2. I set up a workspace with a workspace name and username and password. I don't know what to enter for the Connection Name in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer is a client that access to a database server to extract data.

You need a database server.

If you operate with SQLDeveloper probably you like to install Oracle. There is a simplified version of Oracle that is called Oracle-XE. Search it over google and download the right version for your operating system.

Comment: Ya I have Oracle XE 11-g version 2. Creat local database still isnt showing up.

Comment: Is your database running? Check it. You have to manually start it if it is not a service that starts automatically when your pc is switched on. You can test it with a telnet call on the database port something like: telnet 127.0.0.1 1521 or similar

Comment: So it is not present in your pc.

Comment: can you provide a link to what I need to download please
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: I'm able to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4500:1000:2405754666672024::::: which is the Oracle database web application. I made a workspace and user and such.

Answer (score 0):

Give the username and password of the user you created. You can specify localhost in Host name. If you haven't modified the port on which Oracle works then give 1521. If you haven't changed SID as well then give XE. You might be able to connect with DB.